# US B1/B2 visa renewal - consulate interview questions

Tags: b1-b2-visas, proof-of-employment, visa-renewals, interview

I'm renewing my b1/b2 visa in another country where I currently live, 10 years after the previous one. Had my original appointment when the pandemic started so they pushed all of them for 2023. Do I have to update my DS-160 with my current information? The only change is my new job and some other countries I have visited in the mean time.

Being a renewal in another country, I was forced to have an interview with a consulte officer. How detailed do their questions go to prove my ties to my current country? Will they call my previous employer? Should I update the form? Or just let them know in person?

Thanks!

Comment: "How detailed do their questions go..." - We applied (not renewal) for b1/b2 in our country of legal residence (not citizens).  We (family of 6) were asked a total of 1 question in the interview - what is my highest level of education (or something like that).  We answered that and the officer said "OK you're approved..."  Didn't ask about ties to home country, didn't ask why we were in new country, didn't ask to see anything else.